# One reserved IP address: "network address of all 0s"?

Tags: networking

It's interpreted as "this network or segment". Here the "network address" is versus host address.

My question: under what circumstances is such an IP address used?

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing more than a "notational convention"; a convenient way of talking about a network, according to the earliest reference to the all-zeroes address I found, in [RFC 919](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc919#page-6):

```
If the use of "all ones" in a field of an IP address means
"broadcast", using "all zeros" could be viewed as meaning
"unspecified".  There is probably no reason for such addresses to
appear anywhere but as the source address of an ICMP Information
Request datagram.  However, as a notational convention, we refer to
networks (as opposed to hosts) by using addresses with zero fields.
For example, 36.0.0.0 means "network number 36" while 36.255.255.255
means "all hosts on network number 36".
```

For example, if I were to say "it's 10.0.0.0/16", you would know I was talking about a subnet, and not a host. If I were to say "it's 10.0.4.16/16", you would know I was talking about a host.

In practice, some IP stacks interpreted this as an alternate form of the broadcast address. But (as the RFC states) you will probably never see it on the network.

Comment: What you're talking about is all 0s or 1s in node address instead of network address.  I figure the context should be about routing. However, I just could not senseful examples...

Comment: @CCNA, your statement doesn't make sense to me. If I have a remote address, like `10.0.10.0`, I can't tell by looking if that's a host or a network. Only when you qualify it with `10.0.10.0/16` would I know it's a host, or `10.0.10.0/24` would I know it's a network. The question doesn't make sense until you start talking about addresses paired with a subnet mask / prefix length.

Comment: 10.0.10.0/16 is a very strange way to specify a host address - if anything, I'd think it would be 10.0.10.0/32. For most practical purposes, though, the context is enough info. Programs are generally either accepting a host address or a network address, not trying to infer it based on 0s at the end. The latter mechanism doesn't even work for some subnets, like ones that have more than 24 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Any software that opens server sockets to listen on any available interface will listen on `0.0.0.0:port`.

For example, C#'s [`IPAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) field behaves in this manner.

> The Any field is equivalent to 0.0.0.0 in dotted-quad notation.

Comment: This is not the context I'm talking about... Here is a link to make myself clear. http://www.gtcc-it.net/billings/notes1.htm   And check "exclusions to IP addressing".

I understood those IP addresses are not routable, and they're not assigned to any host. Then how are they used?

Comment: It means more or less the same thing in that circumstance, "let the software decide which interface is "closest".

Answer (score 1):

The Network address of all 0s   Represents `this network`. For example 0.0.0.120    For sending broadcast messages to the network.

The network address of all 1s   Represents `all networks`.  sending broadcast messages to all networks.

What everyone is confused about is in between Network Address, Broadcast Address, and Network  which is opposite

Network Address:  Its a Network with all host bit's Zero i.e., `10.0.0.0` is a Network Address

and

Broadcast Address: It is the one with all host bits ones i.e., `10.255.255.255` is a Broadcast Address